# Control a loop in thread in python

Tags: python, multithreading

I already asked my question but It was too complicated to understand. So it is the question in a very simple way.
What I want is to have flow control on a loop with thread in a class in python3.
Suppose this code:

```
import threading
from time import sleep


class someclass(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        super(someclass, self).__init__()
        self.stop_event = False

    def poll(self):
        print("your main function is running")
        for i in range (0,50):
            print("i=",i)
            sleep(0.5)

    def stop(self):
        print("stopping the thread")
        self.stop_event = True


    def stopped(self):
        return self.stop_event

    def run(self):
        print("stop_event: ",self.stop_event)
        while not self.stopped():
            for i in range (0,50):
                print("i=",i)
                sleep(0.5)

if __name__=='__main__':
    thr=someclass()
    print("starting the thread #1")
    thr.start()
    sleep(10)
    print("stopping the thread #1")
    thr.stop()
    sleep(10)
    thr2=someclass()
    print("starting the thread #2")
    thr2.start()
    sleep(10)
    print("stopping the thread #2")
    thr2.stop()
    sleep(10)
    print("Exiting the whole program")
```

so the output would be something like this:

```
starting the thread #1
stop_event:  False
i= 0
i= 1
...
i= 17
i= 18
i= 19
stopping the thread #1
stopping the thread
i= 20
i= 21
i= 22
...
i= 38
i= 39
starting the thread #2
stop_event:  False
i= 0
i= 40
i= 1
i= 41
i= 2
i= 42
i= 3
```

After stopping the thread with `thr.stop()` it continues to print the i contents but the value of `self.stop_event` has been set to True. what I want is to control a the looping whenever I want and of course I want it to be in a class not in a main body of my program.

Comment: In `run()`, the variable `self.stopped()` is checked only when the whole `range(50)` has been printed, so it cannot detect the stop event before that.

Comment: @Gribouillis Thanks that was it. But If I had a blocking object how could I stop that?

Comment: Blocking methods often accept a `timeout` parameter that you can use to unblock them now and then. There are some hacks on the web to raise exception in a thread from another thread. This could be a way but portability issues  may occur (between platforms/implementations of python/versions of python). There may be other techniques that I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @Gribouillis The problem seems to be fixed. I also need to say using a `threading.Event` object inside a thread which has an endless loop is not a good idea and if you want to start multiple instances of a thread it can be declared many times and don't try to start/stop the only instance of a thread.

```
import threading
from time import sleep


class someclass(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        super(someclass, self).__init__()
        self.stop_event = False
        self.i=0
    def poll(self):
        print("your main function is running")
        for i in range (0,50):
            print("i=",i)
            sleep(0.5)

    def stop(self):
        print("stopping the thread")
        self.stop_event = True


    def stopped(self):
        return self.stop_event

    def run(self):
        print("stop_event: ",self.stop_event)
        while not self.stopped():
            #for i in range (0,50):
            print("i=",self.i)
            sleep(0.5)
            self.i+=1

if __name__=='__main__':
    thr=someclass()
    print("starting the thread #1")
    thr.start()
    sleep(10)
    print("stopping the thread #1")
    thr.stop()
    sleep(10)
    thr2=someclass()
    print("starting the thread #2")
    thr2.start()
    sleep(10)
    print("stopping the thread #2")
    thr2.stop()
    sleep(10)
    print("Exiting the whole program")
```

Answer (score 1):

While using threadings, you can't use the plain value as the event.

You should use the `threading.Event` to communicate between threads.

Check the [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#event-objects) for detail.